# Updating table_2 data using table_1 and table_2 data / T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Scenario**

`user@website.com` needs to have the same user profiles in table 2 as `admin@website.com`.

Currently `user@website.com` have `user_profile` 50 instead of having `user_profile` 10 and 20.

**Description**

I want to create a query that enters into Table_2 the same `id_profiles` for `user_email` `user@website.com` as currently have `admin@website.com`.

The only knowledge that we have is `user_email` for both users and table/column names.

**Table 1**

| id_user | user_email |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | admin@website.com |
| 2 | user@website.com |

**Table 2**

| id_user | user_profile |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 50 |

**Table 2** (expected data):

| id_user | user_profile |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 |

Below query doesn't work as expected as it only inserts data when there are no rows with user_id '2' in Table_2.

```
DECLARE @adminEmail nvarchar(255) = 'admin@website.com'
DECLARE @userEmail nvarchar(255) = 'user@website.com'
DECLARE @adminEmailID int = (SELECT id_user FROM Table_1 
                             WHERE user_profile = @adminEmail);

INSERT INTO Table_2 (id_user, user_profile)
    SELECT 
        (SELECT id_user FROM Table_1 
         WHERE user_email = @userEmail) AS id_user, 
        b.user_profile
    FROM 
        Table_2 b
    INNER JOIN 
        Table_1 a ON a.id_user = b.id_user
    WHERE 
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table_2
                    WHERE id_user = (SELECT id_user FROM Table_1 
                                     WHERE user_email = @userEmail))
```

Comment: Can you just delete rows for user2 and re-insert rows for user1 substituting the id?

Comment: This is just an example scratch of much bigger table, if there are any rows for user 2 that are matching user_profile for user 1 we want to keep them as there are more columns in the table which are populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MERGE` for this.

Note the following:

- You *must* pre-filter the source and target tables, using CTEs, views or derived tables, because otherwise you will end up deleting the whole table. Do *not* fall into the trap of putting all the conditions in the `ON`.
- You need to find the ID of the target user, in order to insert against that ID. You cannot do this in the `MERGE` as there will be no matching row due to the `JOIN`.

```sql
DECLARE @adminEmail nvarchar(255) = 'admin@website.com';
DECLARE @userEmail nvarchar(255) = 'user@website.com';
DECLARE @userEmailID int = (SELECT id_user FROM Table_1
                             WHERE user_email = @userEmail);
                             
WITH Source AS (
    SELECT t2.*
    FROM Table_2 t2
    JOIN Table_1 t1 ON t1.id_user = t2.id_user
    WHERE t1.user_email = @adminEmail
),
Target AS (
    SELECT t2.*
    FROM Table_2 t2
    WHERE t2.id_user = @userEmailID
)
MERGE Target t
USING Source s ON s.user_profile = t.user_profile
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (id_user, user_profile)
    VALUES (@userEmailID, s.user_profile)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    DELETE
;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b0d1032cdd9988491deb836d62b054cf)

- Depending on the complexity of the joins, it may be easier and more performant to do this as separate `INSERT` and `DELETE` statements

```sql
DECLARE @adminEmail nvarchar(255) = 'admin@website.com';
DECLARE @userEmail nvarchar(255) = 'user@website.com';

INSERT Table_2 (id_user, user_profile)
SELECT t1User.id_user, t2.user_profile
FROM Table_2 t2
JOIN Table_1 t1Admin ON t1Admin.id_user = t2.id_user
    AND t1Admin.user_email = @adminEmail
JOIN Table_1 t1User ON t1User.user_email = @userEmail
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM Table_2 t2Existing
    WHERE t2Existing.id_user = t1User.id_user
      AND t2Existing.user_profile = t2.user_profile);
      
DELETE t2
FROM Table_2 t2
JOIN Table_1 t1User ON t1User.id_user = t2.id_user
    AND t1User.user_email = @userEmail
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM Table_2 t2Admin
    JOIN Table_1 t1Admin ON t1Admin.id_user = t2Admin.id_user
    WHERE t1Admin.user_email = @adminEmail
      AND t2Admin.user_profile = t2.user_profile);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=71aa90ae0970aef54ccd8780c07e1e19)